# Creating a PDF file from JSON object in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xslt, pdf-generation

I have a webservice returning a bunch of fields about my form. The requirement is to transform this data into a PDF file with a defined format of out own choice.
When I say "own choice", it means that I want to define in which order the fields show up on the PDF, what will be the padding / margins etc.., Font size / font weight etc.. Basically I want to design a PDF via code.

I know this can be done from XML with the help of XSLT. I have done that in the past too. However, this seems to be tricky in case of JSON. I would appreciate if anyone can help / give any pointers in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create PDFs in iOS using Core Graphics. Use

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, bounds, dict);
```

or

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(path,bounds,dict);
```

to create the context, and then draw your fields where you want them.

You can drop down to the CG level if you want, but drawing text is much simpler if you stay within UI.